# empty dataTable, Maven JPA JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a Maven project with JSF framework.I want to extract data from the database to dataTable. But I don't extract. I will share my codes. But these codes works correctly normal Jsf web application (not maven).

> It is jpa controller class

```
public class usersController {

EntityManager em;
EntityManagerFactory emf;
private List<Users> users = new ArrayList<>();

public usersController() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.ozgur_MavenJSF_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
}

public List<Users> getUsers() {
    try {
        users = em.createNamedQuery("Users.findAll", Users.class).getResultList();
        return users;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return users;
    }
}
}
```

> It is Managed Beans class

```
@Named(value = "usersBeans")
@SessionScoped
public class usersBeans implements Serializable {

    private List<Users> users = new ArrayList<>();
    private usersController userController = new usersController();

    public usersBeans() {
    }

    public List<Users> getAll() {
        users = userController.getUsers();
        return users;
    }
}
```

> It is xhtml file

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{usersBeans.getAll()}" var="users">
        <h:column>                  
            <f:facet name = "header">Id</f:facet>                   
                #{users.id}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name = "header">Name</f:facet>
                #{users.userName}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name = "header">Surname</f:facet>
                #{users.userSurname}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name = "header">Address</f:facet>
                #{users.userAddress}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name = "header">Phone</f:facet>
                #{users.userPhone}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

> persistence.xml is correct

**In xhtml file, `<h:dataTable value="#{usersBeans.getAll()}" var="users">` Even If I write something ridiculous in value, it does not give an error. I just see an empty table. But these codes works correctly normal Jsf Web app.**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: And your debugging reveals what? Data is in the database? Where is the JPA entity? Where is the JPA query? Is data retrieved by your JPA query? blah blah blah

Comment: Yes Sefa, please narrow down your problem. It is very, very rare that maven has influence on a running application. Java is waaay to broad as a tag and the chance that an issue is both JPA and JSF related is less than 1%. Split your problem in at least two parts. The DB part and JSF part. Check the JSF part if you work with a static array. And read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times (use a good tutorial)

Comment: I dont know that where is the problem

Comment: That is where creating a [mcve] comes to the resque!